# JS: Узнать выбран ли хоть один инпут type="radio" с группы

Tags: javascript

Есть группа инпутов `type="radio"` с одинаковыми `name`, например:

```
<input type="radio" name="someName" value="someValue1" />
<input type="radio" name="someName" value="someValue2" />
<input type="radio" name="someName" value="someValue3" />
```

Как на чистом Джаваскрипте проверить выбран ли хоть один инпут с группы `name="someName"` но таким образом чтобы условие поместить в одну строку вместе с каким то другим условием (насколько понимаю цикл не подходит?).
Например:

```
if(someString.length > 0 && /* здесь условие для проверки инпутов name="someName" */) {
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[name="someName"]:checked').value != null`  подходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (someString.length > 0 && document.querySelector('input[name="someName"]:checked')) { 
    // do smth 
}
```